# How to get Comic Book like Halftone filter effect with GPUImage Framework for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, gpuimage

I would like to apply comic book like halftone filter to an image using GPUImage framework for iOS.
I tried GPUImageHalftoneFilter, but it is returning black and white image.

Expected Result :

http://www.imagesup.net/dm-1313779410784.png

Appreciate your help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The closest filter to the above is the GPUImageToonFilter.

[image]

To achieve the brown dots on the picture you can just add a simple mask png on every picture you use.

Comment: @0x7fffffff That is not my source. I used that filter a few times before and the picture above is the first result on google images for GPUImageToonFilter.